# Pointer giving me rubbish in C although correct in another function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So I have a list:

```
struct list_elem {
    char* key;
    void* value;
    struct list_elem *prev;
    struct list_elem *next;
};
```

And when I try to look at the key and value of it from two different functions but use the same code to try and see what the values are, one gives me the correct answer and one doesnt.

I add elements to my list like this :

```
XPoint xpts[npts + 1];

...do stuff ...

XPoint *pointr = (XPoint*) calloc(npts, sizeof(XPoint));
pointr = &xpts;
list_insert(&w->qr_coord, data, pointr);
```

I then try and get the key and value like this in one function (FunctionA):

```
void list_insert(struct list *list, char* key, const void *value) {

    struct list_elem *elem = list_start(list);

    while (has_next(elem)) {
        XPoint pointr = (XPoint*) elem->value;
        printf("%s\n", elem->key);                           //THIS IS RIGHT
        printf("(%i,%i)\n", pointr->x, pointr->y);           //THIS IS RIGHT

        //more code
    }
}
```

And in another function(FunctionB) I do this:

```
struct list *qr_list = &proc->window->qr_list;
struct list_elem *elem = list_start(qr_list);
XPoint pointr = (XPoint*) elem->value;
printf("%s\n", elem->key);                             //THIS COMES OUT RIGHT
printf("(%i,%i)\n", pointr->x, pointr->y);             //THIS IS WRONG
```

The wrong answers gives me random numbers like 0, 2345, -129953.
Im honestly not sure why it is not working anymore any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: you have memory leak here at `pointr = &xpts;`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan how do you know its a mem leak and how can i change that?

Comment: Is `xpts` local to the function that calls `list_insert`?  If it is, you'll end up with list that points to stack memory which will get reused by other functions.  List elements either need to include storage for the data they hold or need to take ownership of a heap-allocated pointer to the data.

Comment: @simonc no, xpts is in the function that calls list_insert see FunctionA above

Comment: @interjay xpts is an array of XPoints ... ahve added that to the code

Comment: @cxzp because you allocate memory for `pointr` then you re-assign that variable to something else, loosing the reference to the `calloc()`ated memory - you won't be able to free it afterwards, hence the memory leak. You clearly don't understand what memory allocation and assignments are for... I suggest you re-read, from the beginning, a good beginner C language guide and understand it and learn it well.

Comment: @cxzp Your updated example shows that the problem is that you are storing pointers to stack data in your list.  When the function that declares `xpts` returns, the list elements are left pointing to an area of stack which will be reused by other functions.

Comment: @cxzp first tell me that Do you understand memory leak?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan its when the pointer is pointing to somethng that isnt there anymore

Comment: @cxzp **No**! that is dangling pointer, leak is if you loos address of an allocated memory

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan thanks i got it now  im keeping the callocd memory and instead memcpying into i

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be

```
*pointr = xpts[...];
```

Instead of

```
pointr = &xpts;
```

The current code doesn't use the memory you'va allocated but stores the address of `xpts`. And if that's a local variable, that address will soon be invalid. Even if `xpts` is global, `&xptr` is type `XPoint **`, not `XPoint *`

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning xpts to the just-allocated pointr.  This is causing the memory leak.
You need to copy the points over.